# postgres query: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Here is my code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test1' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='123'")
cur = conn.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO product_info (product_name) VALUES (%s);"
data = ("ss")
cur.execute(query, data)

conn.commit()
```

I am not sure why i get the error:  not all arguments converted during string formatting, I can't figure out my syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the string `ss` is being considered two parameters. If you make data a tuple you get around this problem. All that needs to change is a comma.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test1' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='123'")
cur = conn.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO product_info (product_name) VALUES (%s);"
data = ("ss",) # make this a tuple!
cur.execute(query, data)
conn.commit()
```